# Microsoft.oData.Client 7.1 posting only changed properties on nested objects

Tags: .net, odata

I'm struggling with Microsoft oData client. I've generated a Sap business one Service Layer oData client in my Visual Studio c#/.net Core enviroment.
I need to post Order document on the server, including document(order) lines. But, obviously, I don't want to post complete object with all the null values, but only properties set. This is why I created a DataServiceCollection for adding new orders and posting with context.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.PostOnlySetProperties). For Document object only changed properties are sent (as desired) but nested objects (order lines) are sent as complete objects (with all the null values, which is not desired).
[image]

My code looks something like this:

```
var salesOrder = new Document{...//set required properties};
var dsc = new DataServiceCollection<Document>(context, nameof(context.Orders), null, null);
dsc.Add(salesOrder);
var orderLine = new DocumentLine{...//set required properties};
salesOrder.DocumentLines.Add(orderLine);
var response = await context.SaveChangesAsync(SaveChangesOptions.PostOnlySetProperties);
```

Any idea, how to force the client to POST only changed properties even on nested objects/collections?
Thanks RK.

Comment: Isn't this answered here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49097313/3231884

Comment: Not really.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Update: I do not consider this to be a good solution, it is rather a hack, but I've solved the issue by removing a unused properties from entity tracker:

```
serviceLayer.Configurations.RequestPipeline.OnEntryStarting((args) => EntryStarting(args));

void EntryStarting(WritingEntryArgs args)
{ 
    var usedPropertyNames = new List<string> { nameof(DocumentLine.ShipDate), nameof(DocumentLine.Quantity), nameof(DocumentLine.CostingCode), nameof(DocumentLine.DiscountPercent) };
            
    var usedProperties = args.Entry.Properties.Where(p => usedPropertyNames.Contains(p.Name)).ToList();
    args.Entry.Properties = usedProperties;
}
```